# RegEx for Windows Service ImagePath

Tags: regex, windows, service, path

does anybody have a working regex for discovering the path to an executable with parameters?

For example:

1. D:\Main_Dir\Sub-1\test blank\bin\binary --param-1=D:\Main_Dir\Sub-1\test blank\config\myconfig.ini param2
2. "D:\Main_Dir\Sub-1\test blank\bin\binary" --param-1=D:\Main_Dir\Sub-1\test blank\config\myconfig.ini param2
3. "D:\Main_Dir\Sub-1\test blank\bin\binary --param-1=D:\Main_Dir\Sub-1\test blank\config\myconfig.ini param2"
4. D:\Main_Dir\Sub-1\test blank\bin\binary.exe --param-1=D:\Main_Dir\Sub-1\test blank\config\myconfig.ini param2

I want to get the path including the binary via regex.
But my problem are the characters like "-_ ." in pathname.
The parameters can include a binary as well and all enclosed in "" maybe too.
Or the first binary is only the filename or it can have a suffix (.exe) too.

What I have so far is:
`([a-zA-Z]*:[\\[a-zA-Z0-9 ._-]*]*)`

But this select the "--param-1" too.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this

```
([a-zA-Z]*:[\\[a-zA-Z0-9 ._-]* ]*)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works a lot better. But what if there are quotation marks? Can I cover them too esp. they are optional?

Comment: you can probably trim off the quotation marks and then apply the regex, assuming you would not have quotation marks in the path itself.

Comment: I've checked that and that would be fine. Thank you very much for this lightning fast help!